# How to create new PDF in specific Google Drive folder using Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am trying to figure out how to have the PDF save in a specific folder instead of the root directory.

I have tried several different things, I have been able to create a new folder but even then it still ends up in the root directory.

```
function SaveAsPDF() {  

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
var cell = sheet.getRange('K1')
var cellContent = cell.getValue()

if(cellContent == 'JMB'){

SpreadsheetApp.flush();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); // Get active spreadsheet.
var sheetName = sourceSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getName();

var pdfName = ss.getRange("H1").getValue() // Set the output filename as SheetName.



var theBlob = createblobpdf(sheetName, pdfName); 
var newFile = Driveapp.createFile(theBlob);

sourceSpreadsheet.toast("Saved ", "Success");

}

function createblobpdf(sheetName, pdfName) {
var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + sourceSpreadsheet.getId()
+ '/export'
+ '?format=pdf'
+ '&size=legal' // paper size legal / letter / A4
+ '&portrait=true' // orientation, false for landscape
+ '&scale=4'  // 1= Normal 100% / 2= Fit to width / 3= Fit to height / 4= Fit to Page
+ '&fitw=true'                   // fit to width, false for actual size
+ '&top_margin=1.00'              // All four margins must be set!
+ '&bottom_margin=1.00'           // All four margins must be set!
+ '&left_margin=1.00'             // All four margins must be set!
+ '&right_margin=1.00'            // All four margins must be set!
+ '&sheetnames=true&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
+ '&pagenum=RIGHT&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
+ '&fzr=false' // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
+ '&horizontal_alignment=CENTER' //LEFT/CENTER/RIGHT
+ '&vertical_alignment=TOP' //TOP/MIDDLE/BOTTOM
+ '&gid=' + sourceSheet.getSheetId(); // the sheet's Id
var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
// request export url
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
headers: {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
}
});
var theBlob = response.getBlob().setName(pdfName);
return theBlob;
}
};
```

Comment: Tip: in your editor (and here) using indentation can make your code easier to read and debug.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function SaveAsPDF() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  if (sh.getRange("K1").getValue() == 'JMB') {
    var sheetName = sh.getName();
    var pdfName = sh.getRange("H1").getValue();
    var theBlob = createblobpdf(sheetName, pdfName);
    const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("FolderId");
    var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);
    ss.toast("Saved ", "Success");
  }
}
```